# Elasticsearch - what the best way to find all indices between two dates for rotating index set up using Java client

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch, resthighlevelclient, elasticsearch-high-level-restclient

Our set up in ES ( 7.x) is to rotate indexes every day in format indexName-yyyy-MM-dd

I'm trying to find the best way to predict the indexes between two days so I can include them in a search request in Java Rest high-level client

As the guide indicates "*Limiting the number of indices that are searched reduces the load on the cluster and improves execution performance*"

So instead of searching for all indexes indexName-* I'm trying to narrow the index list.

I do have a solution for iterating no of days between *From* and *To* and constructing an index list.

```
for (int j=days; j>=0; i--) {
   /* generate indexnames
   * ( "indexName-" + dateFormatter.format(To.minusDays(day));
   */
}
```

however, I'm worried about including such a large list if no of days are bigger( maybe what I have is good enough)
also trying to avoid a second query ( i can make a query and find out what indexes are available. but not that efficient)

As I know ES will accept indexName-yyyy-MM-* ( wildcards, instead of laying out all the days)

just checking her for any good ideas, suggestions. Thanks in advance

Comment: Usually `indexName-*` works good enough, load on "wrong" indices is minimal. Also you can check `days` and let's say if it's greater than 10 you use generic wildcard, if it's below - you query specific indices.

Answer (score 0):

I settled with what I already have with some toleranc

```
for (int j=days; j>=0; i--) {
   /* generate indexnames
   * ( "indexName-" + dateFormatter.format(To.minusDays(day));
   */
}
```